# Is there any disadvantage in a long term to develop .Net core app which targets Net461?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to generate Well formatted Excel files from .Net Core and found ClosedXML library which runs only on .Net 4.61

I already tested the following libraries which work on .Net Core

- OpenXML - Too many codes for a simple task and difficult for me to use
- SyncFusion - Public / Government Organisation cannot use for free.

I changed the target to Net461, do the dotnet restore and all my codes are still running as usual and I could generate the Excel file with ClosedXML too.

What I would like to know is, is it a good approach?  This is not a one-off small project and I am likely to maintain this website for another 3-4 years at least.

Is there any potential to lose the new functionalities and not able to use new Libraries from .Net Core in the future?

Or should I create another separate website running on Net461 and call that URL from my .Net Core app?  So, I don't need to worry about losing new .Net Core functionalities in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is obviously no way to know the future, but the biggest thing you get with .Net Core over the full framework is the ability to run the app cross platform.  So if cross platform isn't a concern, then going with the full framwork shouldn't be an issue.  There is no question that the full framework will be fully supported for the 3-4 year time horizon you mentioned, in fact I think most developers would feel comfortable using the full framework even for a project with a much longer time horizon.

With regard to missing out on new .Net Core features, many of the features can be accessed even from libraries compiled for the full framework.  For example I use the new encryption libraries found in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography` (that are part of .Net Core) from my full framework class library.  The net .Net Core libraries are just Nuget packages and as such can be referenced from non .Net Core projects.

Comment: Yeah, I just deployed my new app targeting 4.61 and it went up without any hassles.